# Java 3D Coverflow of different views (Mapping 2D Content on 3D Objects) -> Which Framework/Tech

Tags: java, 3d, jogl, java-3d, coverflow

I want to write a program in JAVA that provides the following features:
Show Videos, Pictures, Text and if possible a Browser (doesn't need a lot of functionality).

My idea is to map these views on a (some sort of) coverflow-like gui.
For example a cube which has on each side a video or picture and wich can be spun around by the user.

Now I'm searching for the right tech to do it.
I've found an old demo called "twinkle", which shows some of the things i want to do (Pictures on 3D "panes"):
http://jroller.com/gfx/entry/a_swing_opengl_photo_viewer
The Teaser gives a good impression.

Should I use JOGL & Swing like in the demo? Or only JOGL?
The source-code looks quite complex and i couldn't get it to run.

Is it possible/recommandable to use Java3D?

I'm confused because most of the things I found were rather old articles etc.

Do you have any advise?

Thanks, 
Bob

Comment: My advice to you is to go step-by-step. It's weird that you consider the linked code as complex; and yet you want to expand on the basically the same idea. 3D is the way to go and JOGL is just great. Learn the basics first and go from that. Once you hit on a specific problem, give us a nudge.

Comment: I hoped for an advice in which direction i should start looking.
It's just that i don't want to throw myself into low-level OpenGl programming just to find out that there would have been a much better/easier/more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to go the route of doing it by hand and without an premade api such as OpenGL, you could help to youtube and find a guy by the name of JavaTutorials101, he has a 14 part series on rendering 3D objects to the screen just using normal java graphics and polygons. Than once you have the "engine" prosay created, you could than attach an image to a polygon, or than load video to it, I know the picture would be more than easy, video im not sure, but im sure if you loaded it picture by picture or had a way to stream it in, it shouldnt be a problem.